# android opengl app behaves differently on device, z-far is different?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a simple opengl app that renders arbitrary 3d objects. On the emulator things work great. On my nexus on, not so good.

The model is rendered, but it's clipped to almost nothing in the far z. I use the model's bounding sphere diameter as my far Z value. The code seems pretty boilerplate, it's included below for reference.

The problem must be with the call to gluPerspective(), but I can't understand what about that would differ between devices. the only difference is that the aspect ratio is *slightly* different. I tried hard coding the value of farZ to something real big and that fixed the problem. any ideas?

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0f, 0f, 2f*mesh.diameter, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f);

    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glRotatef(mesh.rx, 1, 0, 0);
    gl.glRotatef(mesh.ry, 0, 1, 0);
    mesh.draw(gl);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    float zNear = 0.1f;
    float zFar = zNear + mesh.diameter;

    float aspect = (float) width / (float) height;

    float left = mesh.mid.x - mesh.diameter;
    float right = mesh.mid.x + mesh.diameter;
    float bottom = mesh.mid.y - mesh.diameter;
    float top = mesh.mid.y + mesh.diameter;

    /*
    if (aspect < 1.0) { // window taller than wide
        bottom /= aspect;
        top /= aspect;
    } else {
        bottom *= aspect;
        top *= aspect;
    }
    */
    
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 90.0f, aspect, zNear, zFar);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glOrthof(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
}
```

Comment: i should note that i'm also making a call to:   GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0f, 0f, 2f*mesh.diameter, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f);

Comment: Firstly, why are you switching to an orthographic projection at the end? Secondly, what is your model matrix when you load the vertex data? Might you be translating or scaling it in Z?

Comment: i updated to include the entire onSurfaceChanged() and onDrawMethods(). if you aren't familiar w/ android, onSurfaceChanged() is an "init" method, and onDraw() is the main loop. as you can see i'm setting back to modelview matrix mode at the end of onSurfaceChanged().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply increasing the zFar solved the issue. I still don't have an explanation as to why one zFar worked on the emulator but did not on the device.